# Looking for progression or series formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am new here. I am looking for a formula where I can easily access particular index value. For example: (*power of 2 series*)

```
1, 4, 9, 16.... n^2
```

For the above, if I give index value `5`, I can know that in the above series, at the index of `5`, there is `25` number by simple formula n^2 (power of n)

Now, I am looking for similar formula for another series which stands like this:

```
1/4, 1/3, 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Please help me with the formula.

I am actually trying to create a slider in my web application using this formula. This is not a homework.

Thanks

PS: I learned these things in childhood but had never used them so obviously, forgot.

Comment: I believe the series has to do something with the large number i.e `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I see no obvious pattern, but since you are going to code it, I suggest doing something similar to the Mathematica code

```
 a[1]=1/4;a[2]=1/3;a[3]=1/2;a[n_]=n-3;
```

i.e. define the first three separately, and then a general formula from where it is obvious. I'm pretty sure you can do this in the language you code (if not, just with an if statement).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your interested in the following series
$$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n-1} a_k =\frac1n+\cdots+ \frac12+1+ 2+\cdots + n$$ 
Then the general formula for each term is 
$$ a_k= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n-k+1}, &\text{if}\ k\lt n\\
\\
k-n+1, &\text{if}\ k\geq n\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$ \mbox{where}\ n\geq 1 $$